# ATI 6770 random crashes and dots

Tags: crash

So I got my other PC working (custom build) and installed Windows 7. I then install the latest drivers from ATI/AMD. When I reboot I see random dots and got random crashes. I also tried a older driver and the problem persisted.
What should I do next?
EDIT Also I get the display driver has stopped responding and has recovered error.

Comment: Have you made sure to [connect the](http://www.legitreviews.com/images/reviews/1673/diamond_6770_power1.jpg) [power cable](http://www.guru3d.com/imageview.php?image=31659)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a new GPU + Memory and it was gone. Also fixed this 6 months ago anyway.

Answer (score 1):

> custom build

That limits us to these options:

1. You've done something wrong.
2. The Graphics Card is broken.

You should confirm your work:

1. Is the Graphics Card properly seated?
2. If required, does the Graphics Card get its extra power cord attached?
3. Does the power supply support your set of hardware? (Sum wattage's and check)
4. Does the Graphics Card look OK? Is it properly cooled?
5. Is the monitor cable properly attached?
6. Did you install the right drivers? Are you sure that it's not overclocked?

It usually boils down to the Graphics Card being in some bad condition when more work is required from it. If you are sure this checklist doesn't help in anyway, your Graphics card sounds broken...

Comment: Reseated it stll... Installed drivers latest december augest It has the power atteched The monitior is OK the Card is OK still crashes n stuff

Comment: Hmm, what about other components, perhaps something (HDD, memory sticks) is interfering?

Comment: I don't think so. Should I run memtest

Comment: @jtl999: Yeah, as well as [Video Memory Stress Test](http://majorgeeks.com/Video_Memory_Stress_Test__d5896.html)

Comment: Running MemTest86+ as we speak

Comment: One pass complete... nothing wrong with ram

Comment: Checked everything. Still happens